# How to download a file in Python or Linux from Google Cloud storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Given a public download url belonging to a download button as

```
url = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/gresearch/maxim/ckpt/Enhancement/FiveK/checkpoint.npz"
```

is it possible to download and save the file using any of `curl`, `python` or `wget`?

I tried using:

```
!pip install google-cloud-storage
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage

from google.cloud import storage
import os

# Instantiate a CGS client
storage_client=storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'gresearch'
folder='/maxim/ckpt/Enhancement/FiveK/'
delimiter='/'
file = 'checkpoint.npz'

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the file.
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# List blobs iterate in folder 
blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file, delimiter=delimiter) # Excluding folder inside bucket
for blob in blobs:
   print(blob.name)
   destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(folder, blob.name) 
   blob.download_to_filename(destination_uri)
```

but keep on getting lots of error one after another. Is there another way?

Comment: "*but keep on getting lots of error one after another*" - maybe you could edit the question to share the errors, along with the specific line of code that causes them, so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked [this example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/samples/snippets/storage_download_public_file.py) to Download a Public File?

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez What would be the `source_blob_name` in my URL? That would be relative path or the link or something else?

Comment: The `source_blob_name` is a relative path, in this case is `maxim/ckpt/Enhancement/FiveK/checkpoint.npz` assuming that your bucket name is `gresearch`

Answer (score 0):

Your code (as is) won't work outside a Google Cloud environment because you need some form of authentication to instantiate your Cloud Storage Client.

If you look at the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html) for Google Cloud Storage, credentials is an optional parameter which you pass while instantiating the client and the documentation has this to say about 'credentials'

> credentials (Credentials) – (Optional) The OAuth2 Credentials to use for this client. **If not passed (and if no _http object is passed), falls back to the default inferred from the environment**.

Going back to your original question, if you find a way to pass `credentials` to your `curl or wget or just plain python`, then you should be able to do what you want. One possible way is to pass credentials via an environment variable (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable)). Also, take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually).